# Managing APFS snapshots without purchasing developer certificate

Tags: macos, security, apfs, code-signing

I want to manually create, delete, and restored to snapshots on my APFS volumes (external, for data use, so not limited by SIP). I'm using [snaputil](https://github.com/ahl/apfs/issues/2), but maintaining APFS snapshots require two entitlements: `com.apple.developer.vfs.snapshot` and `com.apple.private.apfs.revert-to-snapshot`. However, I neither have access to nor intend to enroll (buy) in Apple's developer program, which grants permission to use these entitlements.

On my old Intel MacBook, I was able to sign it ad-hoc with these two entitlements and disable AMFI to run the program. On my new M1 MacBook, I don't want to degrade the security, so I want to search for another solution. I find [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin#Create_a_certificate_in_the_System_Keychain) article explaining how to sign `gdb` with the permission to debug other programs (create and trust your own signing certificate, then use it to sign `gdb`), but using the same steps (replacing `com.apple.security.cs.debugger` with `com.apple.developer.vfs.snapshot`) failed (get `SIGKILL` immediately) with these messages in Console:

```
ERROR   21:05:32.777057+0800    taskgated-helper    Disallowing snaputil because no eligible provisioning profiles found
DEFAULT 21:05:32.777558+0800    kernel  mac_vnode_check_signature: /Volumes/Data/snaputil: code signature validation failed fatally: When validating /Volumes/Data/snaputil:
  Code has restricted entitlements, but the validation of its code signature failed.
Unsatisfied Entitlements:
DEFAULT 21:05:32.777568+0800    kernel  proc 23718: load code signature error 4 for file "snaputil"
DEFAULT 21:05:32.777446+0800    amfid   /Volumes/Data/snaputil signature not valid: -67671
```

What do these error messages mean? Is it impossible to run `snaputil` and manage APFS snapshots without paying Apple or degrading the system security?

Comment: What the heck; why is this hard?  We've been spoiled by ZFS.

Comment: @DavidBraun Exactly. I should be able to manage APFS snapshots as an admin user without being an Apple "approved" developer or degrading system security.

Comment: Anyone ever figure out a way around this?